# Command Interpretation

Tags: linux, unix, command

Linux newbie here. I am trying to understand the meaning of the following command:

```
find / -perm -2 ! -type l -ls 2>/dev/null
```

I know the first part of the command, which is find under / (root) directory, but what does the later command do? Indicate any documentation for further help and learning.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts are evaluated left to right.  The `-perm` says to look for files with a given permission set.  `-2` is the permission, which is `writable by others`.

The `!` negates the truth value of the piece that comes after it, which is `-type` with argument `l`.  `-type l` will match files that are symbolic links, so with the `!` this clause will match files that are not symbolic links.

Combine those two clauses and we are looking for files that are writeable by "other" and are not symbolic links.  We then do `-ls` on those files, and throw away stderr from everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can please tell how you came to know that perm -2 is writable permission for others? As I know 010 is write permission, but why it falls in "other" group?

Comment: With numeric permissions the "1"s place is the "others" group, the "tens" is for the group and the "hundreds" is for the owner.  So -2, is the write permission on the other group